# Dynamically create controls using stringbuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, dynamic

i have been trying to create controls dynamically on my web page using the StringBuilder class..and i dont quite seem to get through...
any help would be appreciated.

i am trying to do this...

```
StringBuilder sbTest = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

sbTest.Append("<input type=\"text\" id=\"txt1\" runat=\"server\" />");

Response.Write(sbTest.ToString());
```

The page for sure displays a TextBox on the browser which is easily accessible through JavaScript...but what i want is the control to be available on the Server Side too...so that when the page is posted back to the server i can easliy obtain the value that has been entered by the user into the textbox.

Can any 1 please help me with this....

thank you so much....

Answer (score 2):

Like [Torbjörn Hansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22683/torbjorn-hansson) says, if you just add a **name** attribute (and maybe remove *runat="server"* from your original snippet) you'll be able to access the submitted value but you'll only have a client-side HTML <input /> element.

If you are wanting to dynamically create server-side controls then you'll have to do something like this:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox {
    /* take care to create unique ID's if you're adding more than 1 TextBox */
    ID = "foo", 
    Text = "bar"
};

Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400369/how-to-create-datagridview-dynamically-in-c) almost about the something I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400369/how-to-create-datagridview-dynamically-in-c/2400416#2400416)

You should do the things properly and not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Creating controls Dynamically you can choose 2 ways, the .NET way, or the Javascript way

Both are seen by any of the other, in other words, creating controls using the .NET way, javascript can see and use it and vice versa.

**.NET way**

in your HTML file add something like

```
<body>
   <form id="form" runat="server">
      <asp:PlaceHolder id="ph" runat="server" />
   </form>
</body>
```

in your script part

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "myTxt";

ph.Controls.Add(txt);
```

you can easily get that TextBox in javascript using:

```
var myTxtValue = $("#myText").value();
```

**Javascript Way**

```
var txt = $("<input />", {
             id : "myTxt"
          });

txt.AppendTo("body");
```

in .NET you get the value using

```
string value = Request["myTxt"];
```

---

*NOTE* All javascript lines uses [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com) for simplify results

Answer (score 1):

Provide a name-attribute and access it with:

```
Request.Form["txt1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from

```
Request["txt1"]
```