# gridview not displaying in webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have to display grid view for the logged in user say for my manager i have written the stored procedure and back end code for it everything looks fine but grid view is not gettin populated please help me

back end code of grid view

```
                 public DataSet GetManager(MTMSDTO M)
                  {
                   DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
                   SqlParameter objParam = new SqlParameter("@EmpName", M.EmpName);
                   objParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                   objParam.Size = 50;

                   db.Parameters.Add(objParam);
                   return db.ExecuteDataSet("GetManager");
                  }

                public DataSet GetManager(MTMSDTO M)
                { 
                  MTMSAccess obj = new MTMSAccess();
                  return obj.GetManager(M);
                }


                 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                 MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();

                  if (!IsPostBack)
                  {
                    GrdManager();
                  }
                }

                   protected void GrdManager()
                    {
                      MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
                       {
                        objc.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);
                        DataSet GrdMA = obj.GetManager(objc);
                        DataView GrdMan = new DataView();
                        GrdMan.Table = GrdMA.Tables[0];
                        GridViewTTlist.DataSource = GrdMan;
                        GridViewTTlist.DataBind();
                       }
                     }
```

here is my stored procedure

```
               ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetManager]

               @EmpName nvarchar(50)

               AS

               Select TaskName, DueDate, Description, AssignBy, AssignTo, Status,  PercentageComplete

               From  dbo.Task, dbo.EmployeeData

               Where AssignTo in (Select EmpName From EmployeeData Where Manager = 'RaghavendraS') 

               And AssignBy in (Select EmpName From EmployeeData Where Manager = 'RaghavendraS')

               And EmpName = @EmpName;
```

Comment: How does this even get build for you? You have two function with same parameter.

Comment: can u please refer in which part

Comment: You have two `GetManager` function  accepting same parameter. unless they are in different class, this shouldn't build at all.

Comment: its not 2 functions its only one if im nt wrong... im calling it using access.. im using 3 layered architecture ..

Comment: can anybody help me with ths please

Comment: please sombdy help me .. im struggling wid ths frm past 1 week

Comment: You just created a new grid where are you binding it to display on HTML ? You can refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400369/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-datagridview-in-c) to create grid view dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You just created a new grid where are you binding it to display on HTML ? You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400369/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-datagridview-in-c) to create grid view dynamically.

Comment: can u plz guide me wat shuld i do nw

Comment: In your ASPX page put this code inside the form 
     `<asp:PlaceHolder id="ph" runat="server" /> `
and After   `GridViewTTlist.DataBind(); ` Just add another line  `GridViewTTlist.Controls.Add(gv); `

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: Debug the code and try to fix it.. because its not related to this particular question of displaying grid

Comment: thnks guys i got d grid view displayed atlast... nt sure wat d prblm was .. but i removed my panel n tried displayng it and i got d result... n i checked the panel properties its nt hidden too...